# Multiple group match in regex

Tags: java, regex

I have an input string

```
invalidsufix\nsubadatax\nsufixpart\nsubdata1\nsomerandomn\nsubdata2\nsubdatan\nend
```

I want to fetch only the subdata part of it, I tried,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('(?<=sufixpart).*?(subdata.)+.*?(?=end)',Pattern.DOTALL);

Matcher m = p.matcher(inputString);
while(m.find()){ 
            System.out.println(m.group(1)); 
        }
```

But I get only the first match. How can i get all the subdata, such as `[subdata1,subdata2,subdata3]`?

Comment: Let me clarify: you want to get all `subpart`s in a whole string after the first occurrence of a specific substring? Can you just get a substring after the first occurrence of `suffixpart` and then find all `subdataN` with a mere `"\\bsubdata\\S*"` or something like that? And what is the final result you want to obtain?

Comment: thanks WiktorStribiżew, I have a block that starts with `suffix` and ends with `end` i want to have all the `subpart`s that starts with `subdata`. The final result should  be all the `subdata`s part of the block.

Comment: So, there can be multiple blocks per an input string, right? Or only a single one?

Comment: I can achieve this by two steps, Fetch the block from input string and loop and identify the subdata parts by using another regex. Is it possible to achieve using a single regex?

Comment: Why dont `System.out.println(m.group());`

Comment: There will be multiple blocks.

Comment: @Thrasher, I want only the `subpart`s. If i use group i will be getting the full block.

Comment: You can do it with 1 regex, but it will be very ugly and  I am sure very unreadable for the majority of developers.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks. I will be using two step approach in the product. Could you share the single regex so that I can learn.

Comment: [Here you are](https://regex101.com/r/XfMMPu/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for a simpler approach, get the blocks first with a regex like `start(.*?)end` and then extract all the matches from Group 1 with a mere `subdata\S*`-like regex.

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/ZIbBFw):

```
String rx = "(?sm)^sufixpart$(.*?)^end$";
String s = "invalidsufix\nsubadatax\nsufixpart\nsubdata1\nsomerandomn\nsubdata2\nsubdatan\nend\ninvalidsufix\nsubadatax\nsufixpart\nsubdata001\nsomerandomn\nsubdata002\nsubdata00n\nend";
Pattern pattern_outer = Pattern.compile(rx);
Pattern pattern_token = Pattern.compile("(?m)^subdata\\S*$");
Matcher matcher = pattern_outer.matcher(s);
List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()){
    List<String> lst = new ArrayList<>();
    if (!matcher.group(1).isEmpty()) {                       // If Group 1 is not empty
        Matcher m = pattern_token.matcher(matcher.group(1)); // Init the second matcher
        while (m.find()) {                       // If a token is found
            lst.add(m.group(0));                 //    add it to the list
        }
    }
    res.add(lst);                                // Add the list to the result list
} 
System.out.println(res); // => [[subdata1, subdata2, subdatan], [subdata001, subdata002, subdata00n]]
```

Another approach is to use a `\G` based regex:

```
(?sm)(?:\G(?!\A)|^sufixpart$)(?:(?!^(?:sufixpart|end)$).)*?(subdata\S*)(?=.*?^end$)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XfMMPu/3)

**Explanation**:

- `(?sm)`  - enables DOTALL and MULTILINE modes
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|^sufixpart$)` - matches either the end of the previous successful match (`\G(?!\A)`) or a whole line with `sufixpart` text on it (`^sufixpart$`)
- `(?:(?!^(?:sufixpart|end)$).)*?` - matches any single char that is not the starting point of a `sufixpart` or `end` that are whole lines
- `(subdata\S*)` - Group 1 matching `subdata` and 0+ non-whitespaces
- `(?=.*?^end$)` - there must be a `end` line after any 0+ chars.

[Java demo](http://ideone.com/1FS9Ot):

```
String rx = "(?sm)(\\G(?!\\A)|^sufixpart$)(?:(?!^(?:sufixpart|end)$).)*?(subdata\\S*)(?=.*?^end$)";
String s = "invalidsufix\nsubadatax\nsufixpart\nsubdata1\nsomerandomn\nsubdata2\nsubdatan\nend\ninvalidsufix\nsubadatax\nsufixpart\nsubdata001\nsomerandomn\nsubdata002\nsubdata00n\nend";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(rx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
List<List<String>> res = new ArrayList<>();
List<String> lst = null;
while (matcher.find()){
    if (!matcher.group(1).isEmpty()) {
        if (lst != null) res.add(lst);
        lst = new ArrayList<>();
        lst.add(matcher.group(2));
    } else lst.add(matcher.group(2)); 
} 
if (lst != null) res.add(lst);
System.out.println(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and explanation.:)